# Why does this API no longer work when called through a php proxy? How do I fix this?

Tags: php, ajax, json, proxy, sencha-touch-2

Here is the API: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

You can see the JSON object if you go to the url

I found the source-code for a simple PHP proxy from here: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/code/216729/php-proxy-solution-for-cross-domain-ajax-scripting

I can visit sites using the proxy, but when I call the API through the proxy, I get an error.  Does anyone know why this may be, and how to fix it?

This error occurs with calls to certain other sites as well. Just included the google one as an example.

`(www.mydomain.com/proxy.php?proxy_url=http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true)`

Comment: It would help tremendously to hear what the error message is.

Comment: "Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.", but it varies depending on what site/API method im calling

Comment: Have you read and followed the remark wrt urlencoding on the page describing the http utility class used by this proxy? http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/class_http/ .  The malformed URL error could point in that direction

Comment: I figured out how to fix it.  I need to call encodeURIComponent on the url before appending it to the proxy.

Comment: @fvu Ah, I didn't see this here.  Post this as your answer and I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That [proxy class](http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/class_http/proxy.phps) use the same author's [http class](http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/class_http/).  Its documentation stipulates that the user (you) is responsible for [urlencoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the requested IURL.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix it. I need to call encodeURIComponent on the url before appending it to the proxy.

Comment: well that was in the instructions on their webpage, and also in the remark I made 5 minutes prior to your answer...